# Got "Connection timed out" when git clone with ssh

Tags: git, ssh

- I got 4 development machines(*Windows*) and 1 Ubuntu server(for git) connecting to one router.
- One machine works just fine with high speed.
- One machine can connect to the server and do `clone`, but has a low speed when clone a git repository.

The **question** is the 2 left machines.

- It works when I do `ssh -T git@192.168.1.111`, I can login the server(didn't block shell login). But when I tried to clone, I got a **timed out error**.

`ssh: connect to host 198.168.1.111 port 22: Connection timed out`

`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

What should I do to fix this?